Excel in both teaching and research as a junior faculty member
I am working as a junior faculty member in a tenure-track position at the Economics department of a mid-sized university in Asia where I am expected to excel in both teaching and research. I have found that managing these dual responsibilities is quite challenging, particularly because my university has high expectations for research output and teaching quality. Additionally, I am required to serve on several committees and advise students, which further divides my time.
Given these competing demands, what are some comprehensive strategies that can help me effectively balance my research and teaching responsibilities while still fulfilling my service and advising obligations? Specifically, I am looking for advice on burden and time management techniques, ways to integrate teaching and research, and methods for maintaining a healthy work-life balance. How can I ensure that I am meeting the expectations for tenure without "burning out"? Unfortunately, my university cannot afford to invest in mental well being of its employees.

Is there a faculty member recognized as successful by the department you could discuss the situation with, a sort of reality check? My guess is excel at both probably means be successful at both, which would likely be quite different.

"Excel" in both teaching an research might be the ultimate goal, but you have to chose one over the other. Look left and right, good teacher have to neglect research, stellar researchers supervise less bachelor / master theses or reduce their effort in teaching. Decide what you want to achieve and try to keep an okay level in the other part.

I wouldn't use Excel, it's not very reproducible.

As part of my role as an academic editor and coach, I provide productivity coaching to faculty and PhD students in similar circumstances to yours. The majority of full-time and even part-time faculty deal with the kinds of stressors and demands that you mention. I'll share some of the strategies that have worked for my clients.
First, physical and mental health need to be prioritized routinely, because everything else depends on them. There needs to be a block for these on your daily and weekly schedules, and they need to become automatic habits that you rarely sacrifice. Treat them as nonnegotiable. The main components are sleep, exercise, nutrition, and at least one daily dose of enjoyable activities and relaxation. Some people might also consider a spiritual practice important.
A common human tendency is that we take care of whatever is salient and pressing in the present moment. This is hard-wired into the brain as a survival mechanism, but it doesn't work well for present-day careers because there are silent things lurking in the background that can make or break your career. A common problem is that teaching tends to get most of the time and attention because you don't have a choice about it: it must get done on schedule and it involves a commitment to others. Then research gets put on the back burner, even though research is essential for tenure. So it's critical to be aware of both short-term and long-term demands and have a system for managing them.
I use written life-management plans with my clients.  These should be divided into long-term plans (5 years or more), this year, this month, and today. If you rigorously derive each plan from the one before it, when you get up each day you will have a plan for the day that is automatically tied to your true long-term plan. So since research is of course on your 5-year plan, it will appear somewhere on your plan for this week.
Next, an accountability mechanism is needed, whether it's your private accountability or reporting to someone like a coach. This could be as simple as crossing things off your daily, weekly, monthly, and yearly plans. But you also need to frequently revisit these plans to see where things stand and adjust your productivity strategies to meet target goals. Reporting to another person for accountability is very powerful, whether a friend, colleague, coach, or peer group. I’ve seen instant improvement in procrastinators when they elect to send me a daily or weekly report on their progress, especially when they also send me a plan at the beginning of the week.
Your weekly schedule is especially important. Set this up on Sunday evening. Ask yourself, “Where do I want to end up by the end of next week?” Commit to specific results by the end of the week, and reserve a block for each task on your schedule.
Personally, I create these schedules in Microsoft Word, print them out, and keep them in a 3-ring binder in a place that becomes a “command center” that I return to frequently throughout the day to see what’s next. There are numerous apps that can serve the same purpose.
Nothing in your post indicates that you’re a procrastinator. It sounds like you’re trying to squeeze extra hours out of your week after meeting the most urgent demands of your job. One way to do this is to track your time use for a few days and scrutinize the results to identify any activities or habits that are sapping your time and that you have control over. Some things to watch for include email, social media, commuting, and time lost transitioning from one activity to the next. Can you combine things like commuting and preparing for classes? Would research collaborations with colleagues allow for the burden of tasks to be shared? Can any teaching or research tasks be delegated to assistants? Are there any nonessential committees that you can let go of after a reasonable period of contributing? Are there department or university duties that you can just say no to? You may need to learn to turn down service requests that aren’t strictly required by your department. Try to put your time into the things that will have the greatest payoffs for your career: presenting at a conference would be a better choice than serving on the student residence committee. For parents, the availability of childcare and a spouse’s willingness to share parenting and household tasks are big factors in your available time, so try to negotiate those.
Regarding tenure, list the requirements and assign a deadline to each one. In the US, the requirements might be three published papers and one published book. Break down each large task into a series of smaller ones and assign a target date to each one. A book usually can’t be written in less than one year. Working with an editor on papers and books right from the initial planning stage will result in a better final product in less time.
The goal of these systems and planning is to end up with fairly large blocks of time that can be devoted to less pressing yet still critical tasks. For most scholars, the big challenge is research time. Smaller blocks of time can be carved out each day, often in the evening, but this isn’t ideal because by then you may be exhausted, especially if you’re a parent. Larger blocks can be created on weekends. Some people are able to arrange their teaching schedule to have entire midweek days for research. Even larger blocks can be created during vacations, during summer breaks, and by taking a longer leave from work or year-long sabbatical. Applying for grants to finance these leaves will help.
I want to stress again that regardless of the strategies and schedule you chose, you should never lose sight of yourself as a whole person and of the necessity of taking the best possible care of yourself as a whole organism. If you’re always stressed, exhausted, and discouraged, what’s the point of all the effort? There have to be large rewards at the end––the satisfaction of work you really enjoy, a feeling of being in control of your life, time for family, friends, and activities you enjoy outside your work, etc. Consider your happiness as essential for your career success, not as something you must postpone for later, “when I have more time.”

While I agree with the pragmatism of this advice, it makes me so sad that the only sensible way to find the time to do the job is to be talking about weekends and vacations as times to work. Many people are not capable of sustaining that pace with limited breaks, and I increasingly believe that academia selects not for good teachers or researchers (though or course many are) but simply for those capable of sustained long hours.

This is impossible to answer without knowing the actual expectations of your university and department. They don't expect 48 hour days and 10 day weeks. "Excel" is poorly defined. Many universities are explicit about the expected balance of effort between teaching, research, and service. I suspect yours is something like 60/30/10, given your description. At a research university it would be more like 30/60/10, though these are just approximate.
I suggest that you have a conversation with one or more of your immediate colleagues who have been successful in this and see what they have to say about how they managed it. They will know the "real" expectations.
Note also, that in a tenure track position, it is your more senior colleagues in the department that you need to convince, not some international audience. Those colleagues will be the ones deciding on your tenure (most cases).
But, one thing I can suggest is to do a lot of collaborating, both locally and more widely. To teach a new course, see if a colleague will share their teaching notes with you to get started. Likewise, collaboration in research can be a good source of ideas as well as a point in your favor when it comes to tenure decisions.
And, if your university (as many are) is willing to give you some release time or give you reduced (or simpler) teaching loads, take advantage of that in the early years.

Thank you for the detailed answer, and I am not sure 60/30/10 or other way around. I never came across this in my contract or discussion. I think this is more like 50/50. What do you mean by service? Administrative tasks?

It is rarely put in contracts, but should be known to senior people and administrators. Service can mean many things, including admin tasks and committee membership. It can also mean service to the community - giving talks and such. At many universities, the details are negotiated annually, usually with the department head. Even the balance between the three elements might be negotiable for a new hire. Talk to a recently tenured colleague.

@user23644521 your contract (or somewhere within it) will state your FTE or full time equivalent, which is 1.0 (whatever that means for your standard work week). The 60/30/10 means that your split of full time equivalent is 60% research, 30% teaching, and 10% service. This +/- 5% is the usual assistant professor split for a US tenure track faculty at a PhD granting institution. Unfortunately, even though FTE usually is based around a 40 hour work week, I found my tenure track time to require about 70 hours, because teaching and service was heavy, and research ate into my free time afterwards.

A sensible university will have an expectation like 60/30/10 or 30/60/10 where 100 corresponds to roughly 40 hours per week. Unfortunately that doesn't prevent universities from stating expectation that would correspond to something like 80/80/40 and then let their faculty struggle with that.

I agree with Buffy answered. I just want to add few more points that may or maybe applicable in your case. Since, you did not mention your country or department you are teaching in, the case is often different in STEM and non-STEM departments. The nature of teaching and research varies in both of them. Collaboration and maintaining good connection with your peers is also a key to releasing work related stress. If your university does not offer perks for mental well being, it is perfectly fine as Asian universities do not have enough budget for such things compared to American or European universities. You can join some inexpensive program in your local area or online. It is at least better than having nothing.

I am sorry, what is STEM?

STEM is an acronym for Science, Technology, Engineering and Mathematics.

Thank you, No, I am not from STEM. I am in the Economics department, which I think it is not STEM.

The expectations of your department and institution are local features that are known and understood by your experienced colleagues, who all came up in the same professional environment as the one you are in, with its particular demands, and succeeded. You could hugely benefit from having mentors and friends from that pool of people who can give you good advice about various professional "life hacks" that will help you to succeed and thrive in your current position.
Here we can give general advice, but the nature of this type of advice is that it is very generic. You can watch a hundred TED talks and YouTube videos telling you how to be productive and successful (while staying mentally healthy and physically fit, taking two months off each year to go on off-the-grid wilderness outings, and enjoying social and romantic success that is the envy of everyone you know). Some of this advice is very good and you should heed it, but much of it will simply not be applicable to your particular situation. So, like I said, for the best advice, find mentors with the relevant local expertise. Good luck!


Specifically, I am looking for advice on burden and time management
techniques, ways to integrate teaching and research, and methods for
maintaining a healthy work-life balance.

Well... Eggy gave some very productive advice and tools/methods (where you have to figure out a system and approach that works for you - and this will depend on your personal circumstances and preferences).
What might help (and helped me) in addition, is admitting to yourself that this is it in academia: This struggle will always remain, and the burden won't get lighter. You will (with experience) just become a little bit better day by day with handling it. So you need to indeed build a system that allows you to manage this juggling exercise. Some days and weeks will be better than others - and as long as you stick to the long-term and shorter-term plans (if not to the letter), you are doing OK.
I guess I'm trying to say: find some peace of mind in admitting that this is it - you are riding a never ending wave and need to find the joy in surfing it (the good thing about getting tenure is that from that moment onwards nobody is going to be able to take the surf board away from you any more).

I think you're right. I almost said this in my answer, but I decided that many careers and most of modern life are a struggle for inner and outer balance and peace. I think the real challenge is not to "get everything done," but to simplify life such that we have a sense of fulfilling our real mission and satisfaction and happiness. The acceptance you allude to is important. You remind me of Robin Williams in the film "As Good As It Gets." He's sitting in his psychiatrist's waiting room and he looks at the other depressed patients and says, "What if this is as good as it gets?" ;-)

Ouch, I always found that film rather depressing and I am in fact a rather upbeat person (which is why the acceptance feels 'freeing' rather than 'succumbing to the facts of life'. You made me laugh, still :-)

Woops, I meant to say Jack Nicholson, not Robin WIlliams. And he was freed, remember.

If possible, you can gear towards supervision. Perhaps some research tasks can be offloaded to students? This benefits all parties involved (students get a good CV, you do not need to do tedious tasks).
I have had some success with this, where several student projects ended up also as joint papers.
